# Confusion matrix in `caret' and normalised mutual information (NMI): Linear discriminant analysis, Naive Bayes and Classification Trees

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, r-caret, confusion-matrix

Apologies in advance for the length of the question, but the majority of this page contains step-by-step coding to illustrate my thinking processes when attempting to solve the error messages. I have split the data into a training (70 %) and test (30 %) set for three supervised machine learning algorithms known as linear discriminant analysis (LDA), Naive Bayes (NB) and Classification Trees (CT) using the "caret" package in R (a reproducible example of the data and the code is below). Each algorithm is therefore trained using a repeated 10 fold cross validation with 100 runs. This is an exploratory classification exercise with 2 classes for the response variable, which is Family (i.e."G8" and "V4"), 12 predictor variables and 80 observations. If anyone has any insight with how to solve these issues and assist to understand the error message, then thank you so much.  This would be greatly appreciated since I am moderately new to R.

## Goal

My goal is to produce confusion matrices using the function "confusionMatrix" in the "caret" package. My objective is to use this function to obtain the Kappa coefficient, classification accuracy, sensitivity, specificity, one-way hypothesis test and associated statistics. From the confusion matrix, I intend to calculate the Normalised Mutual Information (NMI) coefficient to assess model performance. My data is called `mydat' (can be found at the bottom of this page).

## Issues

(1) For the confusion matrices, the output error message is:

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

I have tried different combinations of code to solve this issue and      cannot fathom the problem

(2) My NMI score is way off and should lie between 0 to 1. I was wondering if there were any caveats in my coding or in turn, is there an easier and more straight forward way to calculate the NMI from a confusion matrix (equation is below)?

The idea is to output confusion matrix statistics for three separate confusion matrices for LDA, NB and CT using the function "confusionMatrix" in the `caret' package (example below):

```
#The example below was randomly extracted 
 from `A short introduction to the "caret" 
 package' by Max Kuhn (2015) to highlight 
 what I am attempting to achieve with my data. 
 The only text changed is the grouping factors, 
 (i.e G8 and v4).

Confusion Matrix and Statistics
Reference
Prediction G8 V4
         G8 20 7
         V4 7 17

Kappa : 0.4491
Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 1.000000
Sensitivity : 0.7407
Specificity : 0.7083
Pos Pred Value : 0.7407
eg Pred Value : 0.7083
Prevalence : 0.5294
etection Rate : 0.3922
Detection Prevalence : 0.5294
Balanced Accuracy : 0.7245
'Positive' Class : M
```

## Code for the algorithms and confusion matrices

```
library(pROC)
library(MASS)
library(caret)
library(e1071)

# Randomly permute the data before subsetting
  mydat$Family <- factor(mydat$Family, levels = c("G8", "v4"))

  mydat_idx <- sample(1:nrow(mydat), replace = FALSE)
  mydat1 <- mydat[mydat_idx, ]

  #Produce 70 % training and 30 % test set
  mydat_resampled_idx <- createDataPartition(mydat_idx, times = 1, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
  mydat_resampled_train <- mydat1[mydat_resampled_idx, ] # Training portion of the data
  mydat_resampled_test <- mydat1[-mydat_resampled_idx, ] # Test portion 

set.seed(1234)
```

## Repeated 10 fold Linear Discriminant Analysis

```
lda_mod <-train(x = mydat_resampled_train[, 2:13], 
                y = as.factor(mydat_resampled_train[, 1]),
                method = "lda", 
                trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=100, classProbs = TRUE))

 # Generate model predictions 

 lda_pred<- predict(lda_mod, newdata = mydat_resampled_train[ , 2:13], type = "prob")
 # Store the predictions with the data set
 mydat_resampled_train['lda_pred'] <- lda_pred["G8"] # Here we only want the probability associated
 # with the class (Y = 1), or in this case, `G8'
```

## Repeated 10 Fold Naive Bayes

```
nb_tune <- data.frame(usekernel =TRUE, fL = 0)
nb_mod <- train(x = mydat_resampled_train[, 2:13], 
                y = as.factor(mydat_resampled_train[, 1]), 
                method = "nb", 
                trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",     number=10, repeats=100, classProbs = TRUE), 
                tuneGrid = nb_tune)

# Model predictions
nb_pred <- predict(nb_mod, newdata = mydat_resampled_train[ , 2:13], type = "prob")
mydat_resampled_train['nb_pred'] <- nb_pred["G8"]
```

## Repeated 10 fold Classification Trees

```
ct_mod <- train(x = mydat_resampled_train[, 2:13], 
                y = as.factor(mydat_resampled_train[, 1]), 
                method = "rpart", 
                trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",     number=10, repeats=100, classProbs = TRUE))

ct_pred <- predict(ct_mod, newdata = mydat_resampled_train[ , 2:13], type = "prob")
mydat_resampled_train['ct_pred'] <- ct_pred["G8"]
```

## Code for Confusion Matrices and accompanying error messages

```
#LDA
confusionMatrix(lda_pred, mydat_resampled_test$Family)

#NB
confusionMatrix(nb_pred, mydat_resampled_test$Family)

#CT
confusionMatrix(ct_pred, mydat_resampled_test$Family)
```

Each model returns the same error message and after searching on online and in tutorials, I still cannot solve the issue.

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

## Normalised Mutual Information (NMI)

[image]

```
• a is the number of correct predictions that an instance is negative,
• b is the number of incorrect predictions that an instance is positive,
• c is the number of incorrect of predictions that an instance is negative,
• d is the number of correct predictions that an instance is positive,
• N is the count total
```

Reference: Fielding, A.H. & Bell, J.F. (1997) A review of methods for the
assessment of prediction errors in conservation presence/
absence models. Environmental Conservation, 24, 38–49.

```
#Equation to calculate the NMI after Fielding and Bell (1997)

NMI= -a*In(a)-b*In(b)-c*In(c)-d*In(d)+(a+b)*In(a+b)+(c+d)*In(c+d)
      -----------------------------------------------------------
            n*In(n)-((a+c)*In(a+c)+(b+d)*In(b+d))

#This is how I approached this problem
```

The values a-d were taken from the above 
   example of the confusion matrix by Kuhn (2015).

```
a<-20
b<-7
c<-7
d<-17
N<-80
```

## NMI CODING

```
#I believe the function `solve' is used to inverse a value. Is this correct? 

NMI_top.row<-((-a)*(solve(a))-((b*solve(b))-(c*solve(c))-(d*solve(d)))+((a+b)*(solve(a+b)+(c+d)*(solve(c+d)))))
NMI_bottom.row<-(N*solve(N))-(((a+c))*(solve(a+c)+(b+d))*solve((b+d)))
NMI<-(NMI_top.row/NMI_bottom.row)

Answer: This answer is way off since it should lie between 0 to 1
        [,1]
[1,] -1.0752

#
```

## DATA

```
 mydat <- structure(list(Family = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("G8", "v4"), class="factor"), 
 Swimming = c(-0.4805568, 0.12600625, 0.06823834, 0.67480139, 
 0.64591744, 0.21265812, -0.01841352, 0.12600625, -0.2206012, 
 0.27042603, 0.03935439, -0.45167284, -0.04729748, -0.10506539, 
 0.0971223, -0.07618143, 0.29930998, 0.01047043, -0.24948516, 
-0.04729748, -0.01841352, -0.19171725, -0.4805568, 0.01047043, 
-0.42278889, -0.45167284, -0.30725307, 0.24154207, 1.45466817, 
-0.01841352, 0.38596185, 0.15489021, -0.04729748, 0.27042603, 
-0.07618143, -0.10506539, -0.01841352, 0.01047043, 0.06823834, 
-0.16283329, -0.01841352, -0.39390493, -0.04729748, 0.01047043, 
 0.01047043, 0.06823834, -0.04729748, -0.2206012, -0.16283329, 
-0.07618143, -0.2206012, -0.19171725, -0.16283329, -0.2206012, 
-0.13394934, -0.27836911, -0.04729748, 0.01047043, 0.12600625, 
 0.06823834, 0.06823834, 0.32819394, 0.32819394, -0.27836911, 
 0.18377416, 0.55926557, -0.19171725, -0.19171725, 0.01047043, 
-0.19171725, -0.01841352, -0.07618143, -0.13394934, -0.39390493, 
-0.04729748, -0.27836911, 0.70368535, 0.29930998, -0.13394934, 
 0.21265812), Not.Swimming = c(-0.0862927, -0.074481895, -0.056765686, 
-0.050860283, -0.050860283, -0.068576492, -0.068576492, 0.05543697, 
 0.114491, -0.021333268, -0.04495488, 0.008193747, -0.056765686, 
 0.008193747, 0.037720761, 0.01409915, 0.108585597, -0.074481895, 
 0.002288344, 0.049531567, 0.043626164, 0.049531567, 0.020004552, 
 0.008193747, 0.025909955, 0.031815358, 0.049531567, -0.039049477, 
-0.003617059, 0.002288344, 0.084963985, -0.080387298, 0.067247776, 
 0.031815358, 0.037720761, 0.025909955, 0.126301805, 0.031815358, 
 0.037720761, -0.050860283, -0.039049477, -0.003617059, 0.008193747, 
-0.039049477, -0.003617059, 0.008193747, 0.01409915, -0.015427865, 
 0.020004552, 0.031815358, 0.020004552, -0.033144074, -0.039049477, 
-0.009522462, -0.003617059, -0.04495488, -0.050860283, -0.04495488, 
-0.068576492, -0.033144074, -0.027238671, -0.068576492, 0.01409915, 
 0.002288344, 0.025909955, -0.009522462, -0.009522462, 0.025909955, 
 0.15582882, 0.002288344, -0.04495488, -0.015427865, 0.008193747, 
 0.037720761, 0.008193747, -0.015427865, -0.056765686, 0.079058582, 
-0.056765686, 0.025909955), Running = c(-0.157157188, 0.057316151, 
 0.064711783, 0.153459372, 0.072107416, 0.057316151, -0.053618335, 
 0.012942357, -0.03882707, 0.049920519, 0.012942357, -0.075805232, 
 0.035129254, -0.046222702, 0.109085578, -0.03882707, 0.057316151, 
 0.020337989, 0.035129254, 0.057316151, 0.005546724, -0.016640173, 
-0.142365923, 0.220020063, -0.149761556, -0.134970291, 0.042524886, 
 0.072107416, 0.064711783, 0.020337989, 0.049920519, 0.020337989, 
 0.138668107, 0.049920519, 0.020337989, -0.083200864, -0.024035805, 
-0.016640173, -0.03882707, -0.03882707, 0.005546724, -0.090596497, 
-0.00924454, -0.016640173, -0.075805232, -0.090596497, 0.012942357, 
-0.075805232, -0.061013967, -0.03882707, -0.112783394, -0.068409599, 
-0.090596497, -0.053618335, -0.075805232, -0.090596497, 0.064711783, 
 0.012942357, 0.042524886, -0.061013967, -0.061013967, 0.064711783, 
 0.175646269, -0.068409599, 0.027733621, 0.042524886, -0.03882707, 
-0.00924454, 0.027733621, -0.031431438, -0.046222702, -0.031431438, 
-0.068409599, -0.120179026, 0.035129254, -0.061013967, 0.39751524, 
 0.138668107, 0.020337989, 0.035129254), Not.Running = c(-0.438809944, 
-0.539013927, -0.539013927, -0.539013927, -0.472211271, -0.071395338, 
-0.071395338, 0.296019267, 0.563229889, -0.03799401, 0.195815284, 
-0.171599321, -0.305204632, 0.062209973, -0.104796666, 0.095611301, 
 0.028808645, -0.071395338, 0.329420595, 0.296019267, -0.171599321, 
-0.071395338, 0.596631217, 0.062209973, 0.028808645, -0.138197994, 
 0.095611301, -0.104796666, 0.296019267, 0.028808645, -0.03799401, 
-0.33860596, 0.129012629, 0.195815284, -0.03799401, 0.396223251, 
 0.362821923, -0.138197994, 0.26261794, -0.405408616, -0.205000649, 
 0.129012629, 0.195815284, -0.205000649, -0.004592683, -0.205000649, 
-0.071395338, -0.171599321, -0.104796666, -0.138197994, -0.104796666, 
-0.071395338, -0.104796666, -0.03799401, -0.004592683, -0.238401977, 
 0.028808645, -0.305204632, -0.305204632, -0.271803305, -0.03799401, 
-0.372007288, 0.095611301, 0.195815284, 0.162413956, 0.229216612, 
 0.229216612, 0.396223251, 0.630032545, 0.463025906, 0.496427234, 
 0.062209973, -0.071395338, 0.229216612, -0.071395338, -0.071395338, 
-0.205000649, 0.229216612, -0.305204632, 0.396223251), Fighting =      c(-0.67708172, 
-0.58224128, -0.11436177, -0.34830152, -0.84568695, -0.32933343, 
 0.35984044, -0.3251183, 1.51478626, 0.11114773, 0.27975296, 
-0.89626852, 0.12379312, 0.66965255, 1.56536783, 0.56427428, 
-0.71291033, -0.75927677, -0.75295407, -1.00164679, -1.03958296, 
 0.82139726, -1.07541157, -1.0311527, -0.98900139, -1.06908888, 
-1.20186549, 0.58324237, -0.9700333, 0.22917139, 0.41042201, 
-1.11545531, -0.19023412, 0.25446217, -0.05324237, 0.09007207, 
 1.21129685, 0.62539368, 1.32932051, 0.40199175, 0.44625062, 
 0.60221046, 0.33665722, -0.63493041, -0.282967, -0.32722587, 
-0.11646933, -0.10171637, 0.13643851, -0.57802615, 0.05002833, 
-0.1607282, -0.29139726, 0.13222338, -0.41152848, 0.68229794, 
-0.24292325, -0.11646933, -0.21341734, -0.24292325, -0.24292325, 
0.09007207, -0.34197883, -0.30825778, -0.08696342, -0.8119659, 
0.49683219, -0.13754498, -0.4831857, 0.39988418, 0.90148474, 
0.28396809, 1.05322945, 1.24923303, 0.47154141, 1.27873894, 
0.05002833, 1.54218461, 0.74763247, 0.11747042), Not.Fighting = c(-0.097624192, 
-0.160103675, -0.092996082, -0.234153433, -0.136963126, -0.15778962, 
-0.15778962, -0.023574435, 0.00188017, -0.224897213, -0.109194467, 
-0.069855533, -0.123078796, -0.111508522, -0.143905291, -0.099938247, 
-0.118450687, 1.519900201, 0.177748344, 0.108326696, 0.652129604, 
0.638245274, -0.072169588, 0.087500202, -0.18093017, -0.146219346, 
-0.049029039, -0.125392851, -0.134649071, -0.060599313, -0.086053918, 
-0.197128554, -0.083739863, -0.092996082, 0.844196163, 0.055103433, 
1.971140911, -0.111508522, -0.224897213, -0.187872334, -0.160103675, 
-0.194814499, -0.053657149, -0.206384774, 0.108326696, -0.164731785, 
0.187004564, 0.025020719, 0.057417488, 0.434608441, 0.057417488, 
0.073615872, -0.035144709, -0.051343094, -0.134649071, -0.185558279, 
0.013450444, -0.134649071, -0.215640993, -0.185558279, -0.005061995, 
-0.238781543, -0.099938247, -0.16704584, -0.208698829, 0.048161268, 
0.048161268, -0.037458764, 0.16154996, 0.031962884, -0.102252302, 
-0.123078796, -0.139277181, -0.208698829, -0.118450687, -0.072169588, 
-0.044400929, -0.030516599, -0.132335016, -0.037458764), 
Resting = c(0.01081204879, -0.03398160805, 0.057108797, -0.04063432116, 
-0.13084281035, -0.02997847693, 0.12732080268, -0.1028170581, 
0.08155320398, -0.17932134171, -0.14338902206, -0.02058415581, 
-0.11528274705, -0.11764091337, 0.04389156236, 0.01399844913, 
-0.05755560242, 0.04711630687, 0.0158428036, 0.093485909, 
0.09677967302, 0.02053612974, -0.03608286844, 0.07805238146, 
-9.686695e-05, -0.02285413055, -0.00424187149, 0.01446241356, 
0.03187450017, 0.11323315542, -0.01171898422, -0.06499053655, 
-0.07758659568, -0.07399758157, -0.11503350996, 0.02167111711, 
0.01904454162, 0.05768779393, 0.05555202379, -0.01031175326, 
-0.00458313459, 0.17430774591, 0.00481502094, -0.00928412956, 
0.09047589183, 0.08917985896, -0.05671203072, -0.05333390954, 
0.08541446168, 0.10140397965, -0.02509342995, -0.0369877908, 
0.04609635201, 0.06524159499, 0.0845977309, -0.03239032508, 
-0.03208740616, 0.06264952925, 0.05241547086, -0.03437271856, 
-0.03437271856, -0.06747523863, -0.01270059491, 0.10014629095, 
-0.02872845706, -0.00950652573, 0.04867308008, 0.02486518629, 
-0.05951115497, -0.02353665674, -0.01967923345, -0.10148651548, 
-0.00480936518, -0.00098261723, -0.13970798195, -0.00286148145, 
-0.05492902692, 0.10732815358, 0.11660744219, -0.02016620439
), Not.Resting = c(-0.77046287, 0.773856776, -2.593072768, 
-2.837675606, -1.680828329, -0.947623773, -0.947623773, -2.607366431, 
-0.637055341, -1.818396455, 2.170944974, -0.658126752, -0.808243774, 
2.377766908, 2.111220276, -0.322326312, 2.218858946, 3.920878638, 
-0.304945754, 1.038591535, 1.752268128, 0.907465624, 1.137774798, 
-3.663486997, 2.350924346, 0.067293462, -1.898454393, -2.497647463, 
-4.471716512, -1.465081244, -0.232806371, -3.043893581, -2.323908986, 
1.437404886, 1.079056696, 1.110865131, 1.404724068, -1.706664294, 
0.736746935, -0.005516985, 1.727170333, 1.685228831, 1.836016918, 
0.46617392, 1.697173771, 1.057314221, 0.933704227, 0.482480775, 
0.680713089, 0.090780703, 0.680713089, -0.982921741, -2.281900378, 
0.97208909, 0.027767791, -0.1628815, -0.530221948, -0.385741863, 
-0.972251823, 0.002267358, -1.134447998, 0.626424009, -0.722750217, 
-0.382722075, -0.356550578, -1.851614124, -1.851614124, 1.731465143, 
0.254319006, 2.043778341, -0.28991392, 1.386940871, 0.054207713, 
0.594212936, 1.551821303, 3.100704184, 0.327263666, -1.055195336, 
-1.134447998, 1.730726972), Hunting = c(-0.67708172, -0.58224128, 
-0.11436177, -0.34830152, -0.84568695, -0.32933343, 0.35984044, 
-0.3251183, 1.51478626, 0.11114773, 0.27975296, -0.89626852, 
0.12379312, 0.66965255, 1.56536783, 0.56427428, -0.71291033, 
-0.75927677, -0.75295407, -1.00164679, -1.03958296, 0.82139726, 
-1.07541157, -1.0311527, -0.98900139, -1.06908888, -1.20186549, 
0.58324237, -0.9700333, 0.22917139, 0.41042201, -1.11545531, 
-0.19023412, 0.25446217, -0.05324237, 0.09007207, 1.21129685, 
0.62539368, 1.32932051, 0.40199175, 0.44625062, 0.60221046, 
0.33665722, -0.63493041, -0.282967, -0.32722587, -0.11646933, 
-0.10171637, 0.13643851, -0.57802615, 0.05002833, -0.1607282, 
-0.29139726, 0.13222338, -0.41152848, 0.68229794, -0.24292325, 
-0.11646933, -0.21341734, -0.24292325, -0.24292325, 0.09007207, 
-0.34197883, -0.30825778, -0.08696342, -0.8119659, 0.49683219, 
-0.13754498, -0.4831857, 0.39988418, 0.90148474, 0.28396809, 
1.05322945, 1.24923303, 0.47154141, 1.27873894, 0.05002833, 
1.54218461, 0.74763247, 0.11747042), Not.Hunting = c(-0.097624192, 
-0.160103675, -0.092996082, -0.234153433, -0.136963126, -0.15778962, 
-0.15778962, -0.023574435, 0.00188017, -0.224897213, -0.109194467, 
-0.069855533, -0.123078796, -0.111508522, -0.143905291, -0.099938247, 
-0.118450687, 1.519900201, 0.177748344, 0.108326696, 0.652129604, 
0.638245274, -0.072169588, 0.087500202, -0.18093017, -0.146219346, 
-0.049029039, -0.125392851, -0.134649071, -0.060599313, -0.086053918, 
-0.197128554, -0.083739863, -0.092996082, 0.844196163, 0.055103433, 
1.971140911, -0.111508522, -0.224897213, -0.187872334, -0.160103675, 
-0.194814499, -0.053657149, -0.206384774, 0.108326696, -0.164731785, 
0.187004564, 0.025020719, 0.057417488, 0.434608441, 0.057417488, 
0.073615872, -0.035144709, -0.051343094, -0.134649071, -0.185558279, 
0.013450444, -0.134649071, -0.215640993, -0.185558279, -0.005061995, 
-0.238781543, -0.099938247, -0.16704584, -0.208698829, 0.048161268, 
0.048161268, -0.037458764, 0.16154996, 0.031962884, -0.102252302, 
-0.123078796, -0.139277181, -0.208698829, -0.118450687, -0.072169588, 
-0.044400929, -0.030516599, -0.132335016, -0.037458764), 
Grooming = c(0.01081204879, -0.03398160805, 0.057108797, 
-0.04063432116, -0.13084281035, -0.02997847693, 0.12732080268, 
-0.1028170581, 0.08155320398, -0.17932134171, -0.14338902206, 
-0.02058415581, -0.11528274705, -0.11764091337, 0.04389156236, 
0.01399844913, -0.05755560242, 0.04711630687, 0.0158428036, 
0.093485909, 0.09677967302, 0.02053612974, -0.03608286844, 
0.07805238146, -9.686695e-05, -0.02285413055, -0.00424187149, 
0.01446241356, 0.03187450017, 0.11323315542, -0.01171898422, 
-0.06499053655, -0.07758659568, -0.07399758157, -0.11503350996, 
0.02167111711, 0.01904454162, 0.05768779393, 0.05555202379, 
-0.01031175326, -0.00458313459, 0.17430774591, 0.00481502094, 
-0.00928412956, 0.09047589183, 0.08917985896, -0.05671203072, 
-0.05333390954, 0.08541446168, 0.10140397965, -0.02509342995, 
-0.0369877908, 0.04609635201, 0.06524159499, 0.0845977309, 
-0.03239032508, -0.03208740616, 0.06264952925, 0.05241547086, 
-0.03437271856, -0.03437271856, -0.06747523863, -0.01270059491, 
0.10014629095, -0.02872845706, -0.00950652573, 0.04867308008, 
0.02486518629, -0.05951115497, -0.02353665674, -0.01967923345, 
-0.10148651548, -0.00480936518, -0.00098261723, -0.13970798195, 
-0.00286148145, -0.05492902692, 0.10732815358, 0.11660744219, 
-0.02016620439), Not.Grooming = c(-0.77046287, 0.773856776, 
-2.593072768, -2.837675606, -1.680828329, -0.947623773, -0.947623773, 
-2.607366431, -0.637055341, -1.818396455, 2.170944974, -0.658126752, 
-0.808243774, 2.377766908, 2.111220276, -0.322326312, 2.218858946, 
3.920878638, -0.304945754, 1.038591535, 1.752268128, 0.907465624, 
1.137774798, -3.663486997, 2.350924346, 0.067293462, -1.898454393, 
-2.497647463, -4.471716512, -1.465081244, -0.232806371, -3.043893581, 
-2.323908986, 1.437404886, 1.079056696, 1.110865131, 1.404724068, 
-1.706664294, 0.736746935, -0.005516985, 1.727170333, 1.685228831, 
1.836016918, 0.46617392, 1.697173771, 1.057314221, 0.933704227, 
0.482480775, 0.680713089, 0.090780703, 0.680713089, -0.982921741, 
-2.281900378, 0.97208909, 0.027767791, -0.1628815, -0.530221948, 
-0.385741863, -0.972251823, 0.002267358, -1.134447998, 0.626424009, 
-0.722750217, -0.382722075, -0.356550578, -1.851614124, -1.851614124, 
1.731465143, 0.254319006, 2.043778341, -0.28991392, 1.386940871, 
0.054207713, 0.594212936, 1.551821303, 3.100704184, 0.327263666, 
-1.055195336, -1.134447998, 1.730726972), Other = c(0.019502286, 
-0.290451956, 0.359948884, 0.557840914, 0.117453376, 0.126645924, 
0.126645924, 0.196486873, 0.152780228, 0.354469789, -0.261430968, 
0.176448238, -0.007374708, -0.557848621, -0.213674557, -0.005819262, 
-0.470070992, -0.786078864, 0.006063789, -0.27184265, -0.349418792, 
-0.338096262, -0.165119403, 0.346566439, -0.344191931, 0.074321265, 
0.179825379, 0.278407054, 0.593125727, 0.199177375, -0.058900625, 
0.633875622, 0.428150308, -0.206023441, -0.436958199, -0.291839246, 
-0.907641911, 0.448567295, -0.127186127, 0.024715134, -0.41634503, 
-0.330697382, -0.469720666, -0.047494017, -0.301732446, -0.138901021, 
0.098101379, -0.002063769, -0.02832419, 0.071630763, -0.02832419, 
0.295110588, 0.347112947, -0.083577573, -0.036886152, 0.189045953, 
0.467596992, 0.303378276, 0.218879697, 0.092005711, 0.27011134, 
-0.012909856, 0.262292068, 0.107125772, 0.123422927, 0.299426602, 
0.299426602, -0.326871824, -0.022088391, -0.428508341, -0.014675497, 
-0.114462294, 0.087227267, -0.031519161, -0.159318008, -0.397875854, 
0.101520559, 0.244481505, 0.529968994, -0.32661959)), .Names =      c("Family", 
"Swimming", "Not.Swimming", "Running", "Not.Running", "Fighting", 
 "Not.Fighting", "Resting", "Not.Resting", "Hunting", "Not.Hunting", 
 "Grooming", "Not.Grooming", "Other"), class = "data.frame", row.names=c(NA, -80L))
```

Comment: This question is _way_ too long to ask a Stack Overflow user to read.  Can you pare it down a bit?  For example, ask a focused question about classification trees by itself.

Comment: Hi Tim, I am sorry about your frustration. I have looked exhaustively online to find a simple method to calculate the NMI, and I could not find anything. I  thought that if anyone wanted to solve this puzzle, then this page may help other people who are just starting out like me. Apologies for the detail.

Comment: A small detail. The definitions of `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are opposite in "Normalized Mutual Information (NMI)" heading (e.g. `a` is NOT the number of correct predictions that an instance is negative). Negatives and positives should be interchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the confusion matrix issue, you are giving it class probabilities (e.g. `lda_pred`) instead of factor predictions. See `?confusionMatrix` for details on what the object should be.

For the NMI, `confusionMatrix` will give you a table to work with. For example:

```
  > library(caret)
  > 
  > set.seed(1)
  > dat <- twoClassSim(200)
  > dat2 <- twoClassSim(200)
  > 
  > set.seed(2)
  > mod <- train(Class ~ ., data = dat, method = "lda")
  > 
  > preds <- predict(mod, dat2)
  > 
  > cm <- confusionMatrix(preds, dat2$Class)
  > cm$table
            Reference
  Prediction Class1 Class2
      Class1     78     30
      Class2     17     75
```

Comment: Hi Topepo. Would this code be correct?nb_tune <- data.frame(usekernel =TRUE, fL = 0)
nb_mod1<-train(Matriline~., data=mydat_resampled_train,
                method = "nb", 
                trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=100, classProbs = TRUE))
nb_pred1 <- predict(nb_mod1, newdata = mydat_resampled_test[,2:13])
# Store the predictions with the data set
confusionMatrix(nb_pred1, mydat_resampled_test$Matriline)